# How can I disable mobile mode in Vaadin 14?

Tags: java, responsive-design, vaadin, vaadin14

I have made a web page in Vaadin 14. But it's with my own theme. Should not do that. Anyway! The page is done and it's stunning! Only on regular desktop view.

For mobile use, it looks like garbage, for each phone. I have tried use CSS to cover it up, but it fails for every new screen.

So I want to disable response mobile mode in Vaadin 14. I'm happy with the regular desktop view anyway! So how can I do that?

Comment: One clarification here is that Vaadin doesn't have an explicit "mobile mode". What Vaadin does is that it includes a viewport meta tag that is used by mobile browsers but ignored by desktop browsers.

The default viewport value used by Vaadin instructs browsers to disable zooming and use the browser's native screen width which is typically between 300 and 400px after retina scaling.

Comment: @LeifÅstrand Tackar för informationen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly want, but you can at least start by declaring the viewport meta tag, that you want your app to be rendered using a certain viewport size (vs the device width).

https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.21/com/vaadin/flow/component/page/Viewport.html

I haven’t tried it myself, but something along the lines of `@Viewport(width = 1024)`.

You can also try by setting a `html { min-width: 1024px; }` in CSS.

Comment: Tack! `@Viewport("width = 1450")` solved this issue! :)